Is there an "$\ell$-adic Riemann Hilbert correspondence"?
The Riemann-Hilbert correspondence (see, e.g., Thm. 7.2.2 of D-modules, perverse sheaves, and representation theory) shows that analytic perverse sheaves are equivalent to regular holonomic $D$-modules for complex algebraic varieties. There exist work on $p$-adic Riemann-Hilbert correspondence, such as "Rigidity and a Riemann-Hilbert correspondence for $p$-adic local systems".
Extremely naïvely, I wonder whether there is an $\ell$-adic Riemann Hilbert correspondence. For an algebraic variety $X$ over a field $k$ and a prime $\ell$ invertible in $k$, which coherent objects should correspond to $\ell$-adic perverse sheaves on $X$? I apologise if the question makes no sense at all.

The $p$-adic Riemann–Hilbert correspondence relates two types of $p$-adic data: algebraic/$p$-adic analytic de Rham data and $p$-adic étale data. But what other $\ell$-adic thing do you want to compare to?

Dear @R.vanDobbendeBruyn, I guess that by de Rham data, you mean something analogous to $D$-modules, and by étale data, you mean something analogous to perverse sheaves?

There are no $\ell$-adic coherent objects over a general field $k$ in which $\ell$ is invertible. A coherent object would be a module for the structure sheaf, and thus a $k$-module, or a module for the structure sheaf of some kind of lift, and thus a $W(k)$-module. Neither of these rings is $\ell$-adic unless $k$ itself is.
